# How can I enjoy pager API and yet do GDK cards scroll?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, google-glass, google-gdk

I want to adapt my current Android app to Google-glass

I have a pageView popup, which I want to covert to scrolling cards in Google-glass

(will be scrolled by glass scroll and also by head movement).

I have read this [page](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/ui/theme-widgets)

which fills a CardScrollView with this custom adapter

```
   mCardScrollView = new CardScrollView(this);
        ExampleCardScrollAdapter adapter = new ExampleCardScrollAdapter();
        mCardScrollView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

How can I adapt my code, which uses pagerView:

```
 adapter = new MyPageAdapter(nNumberOfViews, mViews);
        myPager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        InitPagesDots(0, true);
        myPager.setCurrentItem(0);
```

How can I enjoy the pager API and yet do cards scroll?